# How to list a directory that has whitespaces in its name via FTP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Well I tried to send the url encoded but when I start the stream I get 550 error (permission denied, which means that the folder doesn't exist in my case -> probably it compares with the non encoded name on the server). I tried to send it unencoded...and it failed even quicker, the stream didn't opened at all (naturally). I take it that it's impossible to list a directory that has whitespaces?

I'm using a Linux server, but ideally, I would like it to work with multiple servers.

[UPDATE] I've just tried the apple sample SimpleFTP code and it seems that it has the same problem. It creates folders with spaces, but when you try to list them it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know too much about NSStream, I am using FTPHelper by Erica Sadun for ftp'ing, but I presume that the URL either needs to be escaped.

Try `%20` or `\` where the spaces are meant to be. There is meant to be a space after the `\` by the way!

Comment: I already tried %20, and it doesn't work. Will try \ too, hopefully it will work

Comment: Nope, as expected, no luck with that either:( can you list a directory that has spaces in it's name with FTPHelper?  I had a look over his code and it seems pretty regular stuff, he doesn't handle the url in any different way:(

Comment: Ah, I found the problem, I double encode my path, so, %20 becomes %2520 :| my bad. Will choose your answer because is correct

Comment: And the only one! Thanks though :P